# Java UML implementation

Tags: java, uml

How I should make something like that in Java?

[image: UML Diagram]

Right now I've this:

```
public class Person {
    String name;
    String surName;
    Integer yearOfBirth;

    //Constructors, Getters, Setters and Methods
}

public class Professor extends Person {
    String department;
   
    //Constructors, Getters, Setters and Methods
}

// Two Childs of Professor

public class DepartmentProfessor {
    String departmentName;

    //Constructors, Getters, Setters and Methods
}
```

I'm very newbie to UML, if I understood correctly, *Professor* has to be an interface and *DepartmentProfessors* have to implement it but then I've the problem of *Person* being superclass, have concrete methods, of *Professor* and it having two subclasses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mistaken. `Professor` is a simple class and `DepartmentedProfessors` the same. Only that the latter depends on the first one (the dashed arrow line). This is because `Professor` is used in a paramter of the operation `addProfessor(Professor)`.

Comment: So, DepartmentProfessor ----> Professor is just because of the operation addProfessor(Professor) no relationship between them of implement or extend?